# How to set checkbox on JQGrid Add Form to checked

Tags: forms, checkbox, jqgrid, addition

I'm using the Add Form to add records to my JQGrid. One of the fields is a checkbox. Does anyone know how to have the checkbox to be defaulted to checked when the form displays. I thought it would use the onInitializeForm event and the setCell method but I'm having no luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```
     beforeShowForm: function(eparams) {
         document.getElementById('calc_next_svc').checked = 'true';
     }
 }, // add options
```